# Problem reinstalling Advanced Rest Client

Tags: advanced-rest-client

today I saw 2 different versions of ARC in my "Programs and features" Windows 10 list, so I choosed to uninstall the older one because I needed a bit of space. At the end of the uninstall, both of them where disappeared!

So, I downloaded the new version from https://install.advancedrestclient.com/, run as Admin and approved changes to S.O., the program started the installation but stucked at 1/3 of it. I waited for a few minutes, then closed it. Every time I try launching it, it stucks at about 1/3 of the installation.

I've tried searching for registry keys, and simply restarting the PC, with no luck.
Please help me if you can, because I really need that prog.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.  Uninstall from program files didn't work for me either.  I used ccleaner to remove then reinstall.  Ccleaner will find appropriate registries.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using CCleaner, as suggested by Ray above, I had to do the following:

1) In the classic "Programs and Features" list (Control Panel style) of Windows 10, I chose Uninstall, upon which Windows 10 said it cannot find the program and asked if I want to remove the program from the list. I answered Yes.

2) Manually delete the folders "Advanced Rest Client" and "advanced-rest-client" (I had both) from %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming and from %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local (had only one of them).

After that, a fresh installation with the newest arc-setup.exe (version 15.0.5) worked.